# How do you neutralize pH of a solution by not knowing concentration

Tags: aqueous-solution, solutions, ph

If I had a pH 10 in a 100ml solution of water and 93% sodium hydroxide how much mg/l of 93% sulfuric acid would we need to use to reach a pH of 4.

From my dated college chem books and a lot of google searching i know

1.) One mole of sulfuric acid will neutralize two moles of sodium hydroxide, as follows:

$$\ce{2NaOH + H2SO4 → Na2SO4 + 2H2O}$$  (the result is two water and one salt)

2.) 1 Gallon = 3785.41 mL or 378.541 L

3.) pH + POH = 14

4.) In one minutes time we will have 100 gallons or 378541ml (100 gallons * 3785.41 = 378541 mL)

5.) pH = 10 (of our water/sodium hydroxide solution.)

6.) The hydronium ion concentration can be found from the pH by the reverse of the mathematical operation employed to find the pH.

```
 10^(-pH) = hydronium ion concentration

 hydronium ion concentration = 10^-10 = 1e-10 M or 0.0000000001 mol/l

 378.541 L * 0.0000000001 mol/l = 3.78541e-8 moles

 we need a hydronium ion concentration of 10^-4 which is 0.0001 mol/l
```

**How do i put this all together?**

Comment: If you could use simple step by step with labeling each step would be amazing, I know I am asking a lot and I do not know if this is possible given my lack of variables. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: After more research I have been told this is a titration curve problem and my concentration of sodium hydroxide needs to be known?

Comment: This is impossible to calculate unless you know the [buffering capacity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_solution) of the input. At best you could neutralize the added sulfuric acid, but that would only bring you back to around the input pH. (And you're also correct that it would be good to know the concentration of the sodium hydroxide solution.)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's asking about a situation which requires a licensed professional. We can not safely answer questions for your specific situation and you should consult someone with the appropriate certifications.

Comment: R.M, Thank you for your input, the boss ended up going though an engineering firm and its off of my plate. Should I delete this post or re-word as not knowing the answer is going to bother me.